# Use Case Diagram for timetable system

Tags: database, uml, system, use-case, use-case-diagram

This is the Use Case Diagram I made for the timetable system of my college:

[image]

Is my diagram correct? Or does it need more use cases?

Comment: And not geting tired to repeat: `Log in` is no use case at all. It's a constraint applied to use cases. `Log out` is an anti-use case.

Comment: You don't give any specification by which to judge this. PS Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: Re "is this right": Show the steps of your work following your reference/textbook, with justification--not all terms/notations are standard & we don't know exactly what algorithm/method you are following & we want to check your work but not redo it & we need your choices when an algorithm allows them & otherwise we can't tell you where you went right or wrong & we don't want to rewrite your textbook. Please see [ask], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of the fact your diagram is very difficult to read because the text is too small, your diagram is not correct.

- The actors *Director* and *Head Of School* (if I read well) do not specificaly activate a use case, they are useless, the 'relation' between them and *Academic Administration* is invalid, probably you wanted a generalization
- To only allow *Update User Info* at the authentication is too reducing
- The 'relation' between *Change Password* and *Edit Personal Detail* with *Update User Info* is illegal, may be you wanted a generalization like previously and in that case this is still wrong because there is no actor activating these UC, use an *extend*
- It is exactly the same with *Edit Timetable* and the three UCs under
- The *extend* between *Update User Info* and *Create new user* is not clear, I mean one updates something already existing, for me better to not have it
- By convention the actors at the right are secondary actors, this is not the case of the *Timetable Administrator*
- The actors *Student*, *Accountant*, Academic Administration* and *Lecturer* are associated with the same UCs, when several UCs do the same thing that means there are only one role so only one actor must be present. You confuse actor and 'people', an actor is a role.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I have some questions. What do you mean by "The actors Director and Head Of School  do not specificaly activate a use case" ?  For Director and Head of School relation i meant the generalization but I guess there should be two arrows from Director and Head to The Academic Administration. What do you sugget to extend authentication?  Where do you think the TimeTable Administartor should be? And lastly, do you suggest to remove all the actors?

Comment: @Student777 You have to understand an actor represents a **role**, because *Director* and *Head Of School* do nothing more nor less than *Academic Administration* for the UCs that means they are all synonymous. I insist, an actor is **not** a person but a *role*. A given person can have several roles

Comment: @Student777 currently all the actors at the right are equivalent, so you can reduce all of them to only one, but probably you feel this is *strange*, and you are right => some UCs are very probably missing, in the real life the persons do nt do the same thing when they are a director, a student etc.

Comment: I understand your point but for timetable system I thought that only Admin should have privilege of editing timetable and generating the new one. Is it incorrect?

Comment: @Student777 for that yes this is probable

Comment: @Student777 you reverse the roles between you and me. *you* have to decide what to do, I cannot do that for you ;-)

Comment: Thank you for your help!